# Bing Maps v7 pushpin htmlContent causing events to become unbound when not visible

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

When creating a map with a pushpin that has the htmlContent property set, the events can become unbound when the pushpin leaves the map area (eg: zooming in and then zooming back out).

**Steps to recreate:**

Load map
Click pushpin (should alert)
Zoom in anywhere on the map so that the pushpin is no longer on the map
Zoom back out 
Click on the pushpin again (will no longer alert)
This does not happen when the pushpin does not have the htmlContent property set.

I have created demonstrations here:

Broken example: http://jsfiddle.net/wYddq/3/

```
var pushpinOptions = {width: null, height: null, htmlContent: "<div style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;border:solid 2px;background-color:LightBlue;width:100px;'>Custom Pushpin</div>"};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wYddq/4/

```
var pushpinOptions = {width: null, height: null};
```

Tested in Chrome 24 (W7 and OSX), IE9 (W7) and IE10 (W8) with same results.

Comment: got the same problem with Bing maps on Windows 8, has the problem been resolved since?

Comment: It doesn't look like it has been resolved yet. I posted the question on the Bing maps forum and it got deleted with no responses.

Comment: did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: *Edit: it looks like the issue has been fixed. The example I have posted above is working now.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a solution in the Bing Maps forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef4b7ef1-d53e-4385-9e58-775c6a028ebe/bing-maps-custom-html-pushpin-not-firing-any-infobox-event